# Why Quotation Marks is used in Strings?

Tags: string

I'm following a tutorial on Python on the string topic

```
    first = ‘John’
    last = ‘Smith’
    message = first + ' [' + last + '] is a coder'
    print(message)

John [Smith] is a coder
```

Why is ' [' + last + '] is a coder' in quotation marks however 'first' is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first`, `last` and `message` are variables.

You can set variables with equal sign(=).

Also you can combine variables and values with plus sign(+).

So let's check the `message` variable:

```
message = first + ' [' + last + '] is a coder'
```

So actually it's:

```
message = 'John' + ' [' + 'Smith' + '] is a coder'
```

Actually you mean 'John' if you write `first`. Because you set that variable at first line.

Comment: So the tutorial made a mistake by not putting 'first' in quotations also? Because everything else is in quotations except 'first'

Comment: @Blenderinho first and last not in quotations.

Comment: message = first + ' [' + last + '] is a coder' - here everything is between quotations except 'first'

Comment: quotation 1: ' [' and

quotation 2: '] is a coder'. Quotation is closing by another quotation.

Comment: I see. Why are the quotation marks located there?

Comment: @Blenderinho If you want to use a string value like Blenderinho, you have to use Quotation marks. But If you want to use a numeric value, then you don't use. name = 'Blenderinho' and favoriteNumber = 42

Answer (score 0):

Strings are just a list of characters. In Python, you can "add" strings to join them together, AKA "concatenate" them.

`first` and `last` are variables set to the strings `John` and `Smith` respectively. Wherever you use them in the code, they will be replaced by their respective string.

So message concatenates `first + ' [' + last + '] is a coder` --> `John [Smith] is a coder`. The non-variables here are the first space & open bracket  `[` and the last part `] is a coder`.

This allows us to simply change the variables first and last to create many new strings with the same form.